# how to remove semi-duplicate lines with notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a large text file and I need to remove lines that are "almost" identical (start with the same 4,5,6 words and in some cases the two lines are only different by one or more characters)

for example :

Which member of the Rolling Stones was best man at Keith Richard’s wedding?

Which member of the Rolling Stones was bestt man at Keith Richard’s wedding ?

Which member of the Rolling Stones was best man att Keith Richard’s wedding?

I need to keep only one of them ...

I tried removing duplicates but notepad++ doesn't recognize them as duplicates, any ideas ??

UPDATE : another solution that could help me is to remove lines starting with the same 5 words (only keeping one of them)

Comment: Notepad++ won't do this. No regex will help... you may need some data mining deduplication method, look in to e.g. "edit distance"

Comment: can't i even remove lines starting with the same 5 words ?

Comment: You would need to compare parts of a line to parts of another. I'm not aware if any Notepad++ tool that can do this (regex doesn't compare like that). Although,  you can probably do this fairly easily in your favourite language (Java e.g.)